Picking up the body post request from FastAPI server
I wonder how to pick up the body post request from a FastAPI server in order to transform this body to making a new body to post another server.
But it does not seem like in express javascript when we could reach the body by using the expression req.body.
I have searched in the documentation but I have not found any example.
Is there any equivalent for this in python fast api ?
EDIT :
here is my current code. After some researchs, it seems that we have to create some class to parse the body but I am not sure...
import json
from random import random

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Body(BaseModel):
    title: str

@app.post("/posts/")
async def posts(body: Body):
    number=random()
    title = body
    posts[number]={
        "msgtype":"PostCreated",
        "data":{
            "id": number,
            "title": title,
        }
    }
    return posts[number]


Are you looking to transform/parse the body into some other structure like a class or a dict? You can try to see how to unpack a dict into a class. That should give you an idea about it.

To parse the body, it is indeed necessary to create some classes thanks to pydantic to achieve my goal. Here is the final code.
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()
msgs=dict()

class Body(BaseModel):
    title: str
@app.post("/posts/")
async def posts(body: Body):
    number= len(msgs)+1
    title = body
    msgs[number]= {
            "type": "PostCreated",
            "data": {
                "id": number,
                "title": title.title
            }
        }

    return msgs
@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return  msgs

